# Is the Spring Rate for a Belleville Spring Linear?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, springs

Belleville disc springs are usually spec'd with a free height, loaded height, and loaded force.  From this information you can calculate the average spring rate of a belleville spring.  However, what I would like to know if if the force is actually linear (or nearly linear).

I assume it is not, but don't know what curve the force might follow.  Is there an equation that can predict the force-curve (plot of force versus height) of a belleville spring given ID, OD, free height, and thickness?

Comment: From anecdotal experience, the rate gradually rises as you compress it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curve is not linear.

$s = $ actual deflection (mm)
$h_o = $ total possible deflection (mm)
$F = $ actual load (N)
$F_c = $ designed limit load (N)

[image]
[Here](https://www.spirol.com/library/sub_catalogs/dsc-Deflection_and_Load_Characteristics_us.pdf) you can see the original archive with the ploted graph from one industry (I usualy use this material for reference about these type of spring).

I don't know the exact formula. But the reasoning should be (this is my guess):

- From 0% Force to ~70% force should be affected mostly by the
  compression between the inner diameter and outer diameter.
- From ~70% Force to 100% should be affected mostly by bending.